# DateTimePicker hiding some character while width has been increased

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

I have used datetimepicker on my windows form. I have selected custom format "dd-MMM-yyyy".

The problem is that, it is hiding last character of year.

for e.g. if the date is 21-june-2014 then it is displaying on "21-june-201"

Can anybody help.

Comment: Show us your code. Could be getting cut off on the display or something as well.

Comment: try to increase the width of the datetimepicker

Answer (score 1):

try to increase the width of the datetimepicker, depending your resolution occur these kind of problems, if not solve i think better option is go to datetimepicker properties and choose option short in "Format", this way format will be small like 21/06/2014.